# Creating Progress dialog while switching from one activity to another

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have a custom DialogFragment. I want to show this dialog while switching my activities.

Scenario:-
1) In actvity1 I start the dialog.
2) Start a asynctask class.
3) Do some authentication in doInBackground().
4) Start new actvity from onPostExecute().

Issue:-

The dialog stops before the asynctask.

Here is my code:-

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient()
        {


        @Override
            public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url,
                    Bitmap favicon) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                redirected =view.getUrl();
                redirected=  Uri.decode(redirected);

                if(redirected!=null && redirected.contains(string1))
                {

                    myprogressDialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "Wait");
                }



            }

            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPageFinished(view, url);


                if(redirected!=null && redirected.contains(mystring) )
                {


                    myWebView.stopLoading();

                    String authorizationContentString =  myurl


                    new Authentication(Activity2.this, myprogressDialog, url).execute(authorizationString);


                }

private static class ProgressDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
        {
             public static ProgressDialogFragment newInstance()
                {
                    return new ProgressDialogFragment();
                }

                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setStyle(STYLE_NO_FRAME, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
                }

                @Override
                public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
                {
                    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_progress, container, false);
                }
        }
```

Authentication.java

```
    @Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    super.onPreExecute();

    /*  progDia.show(man, "wait");
      progDia= new Utility.ProgressDialogFragment().newInstance();*/

}

public AuthenticateDevice(Details1 myContext, ProgressDialogFragment myprogressDialog, String Url)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    mContext = myContext;
    this.progDia = myprogressDialog;
    this.Url = Url;
    this.mActivity = myContext;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Some authentication
            return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    if(progDia!=null&&progDia.isVisible())
    {
        progDia.dismiss();
    }
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(mContext, Activity2.class);





    myIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    mContext.startActivity(myIntent);
    mActivity.finish();
}
```

Comment: Why don't you create the progress dialog in `onPreExecute` and dismiss it in `onPostExecute`?

Comment: the above comment makes sense! or try calling progressBar.show() before onPageStarted(), that should work ideally.

Comment: @stack_ved I want to actually show the progressdialog when the url redirects to a certain url. this works fine. But it should when the new activity starts

Comment: so, you want the progress bar to show up while the url laods +  redirects + authenticates. all these should happen with the progress bar in front? and is the dialog getting dismissed even before calling this line "new Authentication(Activity2.this, myprogressDialog, url).execute(authorizationString);"

Comment: @stack_ved yes thats exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code to show progress dialog in async

```
ProgressDialog pd;

class MYAsync extends AsyncTask<Void , Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {             
            //   pd.setTitle("Please Wait");
            pd.setMessage("Working...");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String sResponse) {
            pd.dismiss();
            pd.cancel();


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I want to start the progressdialog before the Asynctask. ie before I call the asynctask and end it after the new activity starts

Comment: Do you what else you want to perform after progressdialog

Comment: You can do it after the second activity starts, it is possible, but that will be dirty as you will have to pass reference of your current activity to ProgressDialogFragment so that it has a valid parent at all point in time.

Comment: @stack_ved Iam loading a login page in the webview. When the user logs in he is redirected to a page where he is authenticated. This page shows "You are authenticated" message. Then the next activity starts. I am catching the first redirected url after login, showing a dialog until next activity starts so that the "You are authenticated" page is not shown to the user and instead he sees the dialog box all the time till next activity

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate it, it appears to be working fine. this below method has comments explaining your actions.

```
private void myWOrk() {

    try {

         final ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
         Dialog.setMessage("Loading route...");
         Dialog.show();

        Thread.sleep(2000);// load url and redirect
        //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "redirect caught", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new AsyncTask<Object, Object, Object>() {

            protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);// authenticate
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {

                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "onPostExecute", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Dialog.dismiss();// start your new activity here

            };

        }.execute(null, null, null);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}`
```